# MySQL JOIN two tables and filter.

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables concerned tables in MySQL database.

> Restaurants
>
> Likes

A user can like one or more restaurants, user_id and restaurant_id are stored in the Likes table to reference the two tables. So as you can imagine, I have a 1 to M model.

Now I want to return all the restaurants and their like information without duplicates. If a restaurant is not liked by the current user the restaurant should still be returned. So I thought of using LEFT JOIN but I am still having issues as explained below.

The queries I tried are below.

```
SELECT restaurants. * , likes.resid, likes.userid
   FROM restaurants
   LEFT JOIN likes ON restaurants.id = likes.resid WHERE likes.userid is NULL OR likes.userid = 'current_user';
```

And

```
SELECT restaurants. * , likes.resid, likes.userid
   FROM restaurants
   LEFT JOIN likes ON restaurants.id = likes.resid;
```

The problem with the above queries are, the first one returns restaurants that are liked by the current user and ignores restaurants liked by others while the second one returns duplicates.

Comment: what is the point of this filter "likes.userid = 'current_user'" if you want to return all restaurants with their likes from all users?

Comment: The second one returns duplicate how???  Sample output and expected sample output would help.

Comment: @isaace I wanted to show likes to show likes to the current user together with the restaurant information.

Comment: @Eric, if two user likes the same restaurant then a SIMPLE LEFT join will return the restaurant details twice.

Comment: In that case, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the filter along with the left join:

```
SELECT restaurants. * , likes.resid, likes.userid
FROM restaurant
LEFT JOIN likes ON restaurants.id = likes.resid AND likes.userid = 'current_user'
```

When you put a filter to the 2nd table(likes table) in your `WHERE` clause, the filter gets applied to the entire result set. This becomes like a regular join because all other restaurants `likes.userid` are not = to `'current_user'` and they would get filtered out.

To fix this, you add the filter on the join instead of the `Where` clause.

Comment: This seems to have fixed the problem, for now, I am doing more testing and I will get back to you later. Can you explain why WHERE clause is not working? Elaborate more on your answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just a simple `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT restaurants. * , likes.resid, likes.userid
FROM restaurants
LEFT JOIN likes ON restaurants.id = likes.resid
```

Comment: The would return duplicate restaurant details if two users like the same restaurant.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use GROUP BY for avoid duplicate valus..